# How to check if element has any children in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Simple question, I have an element which I am grabbing via `.getElementById ()`. How do I check if it has any children?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

A couple of ways:

```
if (element.firstChild) {
    // It has at least one
}
```

or the `hasChildNodes()` function:

```
if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
    // It has at least one
}
```

or the `length` property of `childNodes`:

```
if (element.childNodes.length > 0) { // Or just `if (element.childNodes.length)`
    // It has at least one
}
```

If you only want to know about child *elements* (as opposed to text nodes, attribute nodes, etc.) on all modern browsers (and IE8 — in fact, even IE6) you can do this: *(thank you [Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851498/florian-margaine)!)*

```
if (element.children.length > 0) { // Or just `if (element.children.length)`
    // It has at least one element as a child
}
```

That relies on the [`children`](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-children) property, which wasn't defined in [DOM1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/), [DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/), *or* [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/), but which has near-universal support. (It works in IE6 and up and Chrome, Firefox, and Opera at *least* as far back as November 2012, when this was originally written.) If supporting older mobile devices, be sure to check for support.

If you don't need IE8 and earlier support, you can also do this:

```
if (element.firstElementChild) {
    // It has at least one element as a child
}
```

That relies on [`firstElementChild`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-firstelementchild). Like `children`, it wasn't defined in DOM1-3 either, but unlike `children` it wasn't added to IE until IE9. The same applies to [`childElementCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/childElementCount):

```
if (element.childElementCount !== 0) {
    // It has at least one element as a child
}
```

If you want to stick to something defined in DOM1 (maybe you have to support really obscure browsers), you have to do more work:

```
var hasChildElements, child;
hasChildElements = false;
for (child = element.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
    if (child.nodeType == 1) { // 1 == Element
        hasChildElements = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

All of that is part of [DOM1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1451460987), and nearly universally supported.

It would be easy to wrap this up in a function, e.g.:

```
function hasChildElement(elm) {
    var child, rv;

    if (elm.children) {
        // Supports `children`
        rv = elm.children.length !== 0;
    } else {
        // The hard way...
        rv = false;
        for (child = element.firstChild; !rv && child; child = child.nextSibling) {
            if (child.nodeType == 1) { // 1 == Element
                rv = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize `children` was only added in DOM4. Knowing it was supported in any known browser, I thought this was pretty much DOM0/1.

Comment: how do i check if any `div` has element `div` having specific class say `xyz` ?

Comment: firstChild and hasChildNodes return any node, not only children (nodeType==1). You should correct that. ;-)

Comment: @AdrianMaire: The question doesn't ask about child **elements**, it asks about children. But I also addressed child elements in the answer, just read a little further.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Usually (because of the .children property), children refer to child elements. Anyway, it's ok.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: Well, as I said, all you had to do was actually finish reading the answer...

Comment: Never seen a loop condition like `for (child = element.firstChild;
             child;
             child = child.nextSibling
            )`, voted. Thanks T.J.

Comment: Using Chrome 45 I had trouble with the first suggestion in this answer.
Browser entered if block when I put `if (element.firstChild)` as condition (improperly) but did not enter when I put `if(element.children.length)` (properly). If others see the same behavior, this otherwise very good answer should be updated.

Comment: @Aaron: It's entirely possible for `element.firstChild` to be non-`null` when `element.children.length` is `0`: `firstChild` and such relate to *nodes* including elements, text nodes, comment notes, etc.; `children` is purely a list of *element* children. On modern browsers you can use `firstElementChild` instead.

Comment: Instead of working with returnValue ( rv ) and break: Wouldn't it be sufficient to return ( true | false ) ??

Comment: @michael.zech: Yes, with a `for` loop, it would. It would also give you multiple exit points from the function, which some consider a maintenance issue. I'm a bit surprised to see it above, normally in something that short I'm not bothered. :-)

Comment: For me ``element.childElementCount < 1`` worked. For some reason when I tried to "detect" if there were children, it didn't work.

Comment: @TysonGibby - Wow, didn't know about `childElementCount`. Looking it up, note that `childElementCount` only counts child **elements**, not all child nodes (just like `children.length` does). Perhaps you were trying to "detect" using `firstChild` or similar, and the element contained text nodes or comment nodes (but not elements). :-)

Answer (score 16):

As slashnick & bobince mention, `hasChildNodes()` will return true for whitespace (text nodes).  However, I didn't want this behaviour, and this worked for me :)

```
element.getElementsByTagName('*').length > 0
```

**Edit**: for the same functionality, this is a better solution:

```
 element.children.length > 0
```

`children[]` is a subset of `childNodes[]`, containing elements only.

[Compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t70)

Answer (score 8):

You could also do the following:

```
if (element.innerHTML.trim() !== '') {
    // It has at least one
}
```

This uses the trim() method to treat empty elements which have only whitespaces (in which case `hasChildNodes` returns true) as being empty.

**NB:** The above method doesn't filter out *comments*. (so a comment would classify a a child)

To filter out comments as well, we could make use of the read-only [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) property where `Node.COMMENT_NODE` (A Comment node, such as `<!-- … -->`) has the constant value -    8

```
if (element.firstChild?.nodeType !== 8 && element.innerHTML.trim() !== '' {
   // It has at least one
}
```

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for(element of divs) {
  if (element.firstChild?.nodeType !== 8 && element.innerHTML.trim() !== '') {
   console.log('has children')
  } else { console.log('no children') }
}
```

```html
<div><span>An element</span>
<div>some text</div>
<div>     </div> <!-- whitespace -->
<div><!-- A comment --></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: How does this behave with HTML comments?

Comment: @VictorZamanian nice point! - I added code for that... of course, if the intention is not to include text node and comments as children, then `element.firstElementChild` is probably the easiest way to go :)

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the element has child nodes `element.hasChildNodes()`.  Beware in Mozilla this will return true if the is whitespace after the tag so you will need to verify the tag type.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.hasChildNodes

Comment: Not just in Mozilla. This is correct behaviour; it's IE that gets it wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [childElementCount property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/childElementCount):

```
if ( element.childElementCount !== 0 ){
      alert('i have children');
} else {
      alert('no kids here');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late but document fragment could be a node:

```
function hasChild(el){
    var child = el && el.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType === 1 || child.nodeType === 11) {
            return true;
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return false;
}
// or
function hasChild(el){
    for (var i = 0; el && el.childNodes[i]; i++) {
        if (el.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1 || el.childNodes[i].nodeType === 11) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

See:
https://github.com/k-gun/so/blob/master/so.dom.js#L42
https://github.com/k-gun/so/blob/master/so.dom.js#L741

Answer (score 1):

A reusable `isEmpty( <selector> )` function.
You can also run it toward a collection of elements (see example)

```js
const isEmpty = sel =>
    ![... document.querySelectorAll(sel)].some(el => el.innerHTML.trim() !== "");

console.log(
  isEmpty("#one"), // false
  isEmpty("#two"), // true
  isEmpty(".foo"), // false
  isEmpty(".bar")  // true
);
```

```html
<div id="one">
 foo
</div>

<div id="two">
 
</div>

<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"><p>foo</p></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

returns `true` (and exits loop) as soon one element has any kind of content  beside spaces or newlines.

Answer (score -10):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function uwtPBSTree_NodeChecked(treeId, nodeId, bChecked) 
{
    //debugger;
    var selectedNode = igtree_getNodeById(nodeId);
    var ParentNodes = selectedNode.getChildNodes();

    var length = ParentNodes.length;

    if (bChecked) 
    {
/*                if (length != 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        ParentNodes[i].setChecked(true);
                    }
    }*/
    }
    else 
    {
        if (length != 0) 
        {
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
                ParentNodes[i].setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<ignav:UltraWebTree ID="uwtPBSTree" runat="server"..........>
<ClientSideEvents NodeChecked="uwtPBSTree_NodeChecked"></ClientSideEvents>
</ignav:UltraWebTree>
```

Comment: Please don't just provide code-only solutions. Also, why have you commented-out code in there?

Comment: Downvote: This code is obscure, part of the code is unnecesary, there is not comments or explanation and it look like a copy/past. Also the XML part has nothing to do here.

Comment: What is this madness?