# Checking a parent container for children javascript

Tags: javascript, element

Just wondering how you can check an element (i.e. a div container) for elements (i.e. buttons) and if they exist, remove them?

If I append a child to a div, how can I on the next look check for that child or those type of children? i.e. adding;

```js
example = document.getElementById('div');  
example.appendChild(aButton);

//loop to look for aButton / button type in example div
```

Cheers

Comment: An exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript

Comment: Are you against using a Javascript framework such as jQuery? They tend to make this kind of task much simpler.

Comment: @Saul Checking for children in general, and checking for - and then removing - children of a specific type are not the same thing.

Comment: It's as simple as `document.getElementById('div').getElementsByTagName("button")`

Comment: @Saul I did search, guess not accurately enough..

Comment: @Anthony Unfortunately I cannot use a framework, it must be pure javascript

Comment: @Anthony Grist - Indeed. To rephrase: a part this question is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the childNodes array, loop through and look for one matching your criteria ( input tag with type button, or possibly a button tag)

```
var children = example.childNodes;

for(var i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
    if( children[i].tagName == "INPUT" && children[i].type=='button' ) {
        example.removeChild( children[i] );
        i--; //Decrement counter since we are removing an item from the list
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BZMbk/3/

Comment: I got this to work. The problem I came across personally was that as i incremented, the size of the container got smaller as I removed children, so It would remove about half the buttons each time.

The magic 1 is simply the other child element appended first which I didn't want to touch.


 

   ' var children = buttonContainer.childNodes;
     var childrenLength = children.length - 1;
     
     for(var i=0; i<childrenLength; i++)
     {
      if( children[1].tagName == "INPUT" && children[1].type=='button' ) 
      {
       buttonContainer.removeChild( children[1] );
      }
     }'

Comment: @r34ch The trick when iterating over an array where you intend to remove elements is to do it backwards, so you start with the last element and work towards the first. The indexes of elements after (in terms of order in the list) the one you remove will change, but since you've already iterated over those this isn't a problem.

Comment: @Anthony I'll remember that in future. I'm short on the common sense front today..

Answer (score 1):

To get elements that are of a node type from a subset of the document you can simply do

```
document.getElementById('div').getElementsByTagName("button")
```

This will return any buttons under an element with the id of "div" (not a good name for an id btw)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `children` and then loop through the children. For example if you have a div with the following set up:

```
<div id='div'>
    <input type='button'> 
    <p>here</p>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

You could then get the children an loop through them like this:

```
var example = document.getElementById("div");
var children = example.children;
alert(children.length);
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    alert(children[i].tagName);
}
```

And as to remove them it would be as simple as

```
example.removeChild( children[i] );
```

Comment: This works nicely except it finds a child who is not a button and deletes that child as well which is what I wish to avoid

Comment: You still need to add an if block around the part that deletes to the affect of if(children[i].tagName == 'input' && children[i].type == "button") or whatever element you want to delete