# I need to get the divs inside the main div and if the data inside them is empty hide theat div

Tags: javascript

I have a main dive and inside that there are 2 dives. I need to check that if div's data is empty don't show them. BTW data comes from API.

Here is code:

```
<div id ="select">
     <ul>
         <li><div id="product1" style="font-family:arial; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px solid #b8b8b8; background-color:#eeeeee; padding:10px;">

               <strong>{$feed/API Feed_142197/__data["1-Title"]}</strong>
               <br/>
               <p>{$feed/API Feed_142197/__data["1-Desc"]}</p>

              <div style="display:inline; align:left; color:green; font-weight:bold;">{$feed/API Feed_142197/__data["1-Price"]}</div>

               <div style="display:inline; padding-left:80px; padding-right:5px;">click to call image</div></div>
         </li>


         <li><div id="product2" style="font-family:arial; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px solid #b8b8b8; background-color:#eeeeee; padding:10px;">
              <strong>{$feed/API Feed_142197/__data["2-Title"]}</strong>
              <br/>
              <p>{$feed/API Feed_142197/__data["2-Desc"]}</p>
              <div style="display:inline; align:left; color:green; font-weight:bold;">{$feed/API Feed_142197/__data["2-Price"]}</div>
              <div style="display:inline; padding-left:80px; padding-right:5px;">click to call image</div></div>
         </li>

</div>
```

Comment: As concerned as your code I can see the 2 div situation twice. Do you mean the two divs without id's?

Comment: You can find the solution to your problem by reading [How to check if element has any children in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2161634/218196) and [javascript hide/show element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242976/218196).

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
var div1 = $('#product1'),
    div2 = $('#product2');

if (!(div1.text() || div2.text())) {
     $('#select').hide()
}
```

Comment: And without jQuery? What if the OP does not even know what jQuery is?

Comment: what if? well, it will be much harder for them to code in-browser JS

Comment: I actually meant that you maybe explain at least what jQuery is and provide a link...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern browser, no libraries required solution.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#select div:empty');
for (var i = 0, il = nodes.length; i < il; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```