# How to fill a div with content under the condition that the div has no childs?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, when I have:

```
<div class="abc123"></div>  <!-- no child div -->
```

I want to insert a new div in it:

```
<div class="xyz">some content</div>
```

So that the outcome is:

```
<div class="abc123">
    <div class="abc">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

How can I implement this using javascript?

Comment: Hint: `elem.childNodes.length` or `!elem.firstChild`, `elem.innerHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery:

```
$(".abc123").each(function() {
    if (this.children(".abc").length == 0) {
        $(this).append('<div class="xyz">some content</div>');
    }
});​
```

in Simple JS

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].childNodes.length == 0) { // testing if it has not child
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "some content";
        newdiv.className = "xyz";
        divs[i].appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}​
```

**Edit:**

This following piece of code produces the same effect as done in the above mentioned jQuery code(edited in light of the comment by [RobW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) ):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("abc123");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].getElementsByClassName("abc").length == 0) { 
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "some content";
        newdiv.className = "xyz";
        divs[i].appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}​
```

Comment: @UmairP What about `divs[i].innerHTML = '<div class="xyz">some content</div>';`? In this case, it's still readable. Also, don't forget to filter the elements by class name, using `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.querySelectorAll` or `(' ' + elem.className + ' ').indexOf('abc123') == -1`)

Comment: @RobW Actually, its good since the div has no child to start with. This would have the same effect as my code above.

Comment: In this 
newdiv.innerHTML = "some content";

instead of 'some content' i want to display an array this array is basically set of HTML code. i tried but its not working. so how to do ?

Comment: Could you update your question and show us how that array looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to take a look at this question: [How to check if element has any children in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript)

Seems like what you are looking for :)

Answer (score -2):

With jQuery:

```
if ($('.abc123 div').length == 0) {
    $('.abc123').append('<div class="xyz">some content</div>');
}​
```

Comment: -1 Too much jQuery (question didn't mention jQuery) and it does not work for multiple containers.