# How to check if an element matches the :empty pseudo-class in pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

How can I check, in **pure JavaScript** (no jQuery, no libraries), if a given HTML element is empty? My definition of "empty" is the same as the [CSS :empty pseudo-class](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#empty-pseudo). So, if a given element would match the `:empty` selector, then I want to know about it.

Comment: [How to check if element has any children in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript)

Comment: @Pilot not quite the same. What if it has empty child nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function isEmpty (el) {
    if (!el.hasChildNodes()) return true;

    for (var node = el.firstChild; node = node.nextSibling;) {
        var type = node.nodeType;
        if (type === 1 && !isEmpty(node) || // another element
            type === 3 && node.nodeValue) { // text node
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As per the CSS spec, this will return `true` if the given element has no non-empty child nodes. [Long-awaited JSFiddle demo available](http://jsfiddle.net/y4S5P/1/).

Comment: That being said, I have to ask, why "no non-empty child nodes"? The spec doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: @BoltClock To quote: "The :empty pseudo-class represents an element that has no children at all ... only element nodes and content nodes  ... whose data has a non-zero length must be considered as affecting emptiness

Comment: @rvighne **only element nodes and content nodes ... whose data has a non-zero length ??**.Please prepare a fiddle demonstrating your code

Comment: @BoltClock Now edited to handle comments correctly. What do you mean by "PIs"?

Comment: @rvighne: As far as I read it, the "whose data has a non-zero length" portion only refers to content nodes, not element nodes. You can't really say that an element has *no children at all* if it has a child element node, even if that child element node is itself empty.

Comment: @rvighne: PIs = Processing Instructions, but then again PIs are part of XML/XHTML and not really a thing in HTML, so I guess you could ignore that.

Comment: @rvighne there is something wrong in our understanding of `:empty` selector..could you please demonstrate with fiddle..please

Comment: @Pilot I *really* don't see how a fiddle would change anybody's understanding of `:empty`. See the [link to the spec in the question](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#empty-pseudo).

Comment: @rvighne: It *would* demonstrate that you've tested and ensured that your code works as described. Although speaking as a mod I will say comments shouldn't be used to badger people into creating fiddles for their answers in any case. It's not required for an answer to exist, and certainly not required for people to judge and vote on it.

Comment: @Pilot JSFiddle now available, using a modified version: http://jsfiddle.net/y4S5P/

Comment: @rvighne so appreciated

Comment: Throws an error attempting to evaluate the emptiness of `<div><i></i></div>` in IE 9.

Answer (score 4):

A way to ensure [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#empty-pseudo) compliance is to use `.querySelectorAll` or [`.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches).

```
function matches(el, selector) {
  return !!~[].indexOf.call(el.ownerDocument.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
```

Depending on [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches#Browser_compatibility) needs, [`.matches` is more direct](http://jsperf.com/matches) and even works on detached nodes:

```
function matches(el, selector) {
  return !!(el.matches || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector || el.oMatchesSelector).call(el, selector);
}
```

Use either of those like:

```
matches(el, ':empty')
```

Comment: The [hasChildNodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-810594187) method returns a boolean value that indicates "…whether this node has any children", so no need for qSA or variants.

Comment: @RobG: But `hasChildNodes` alone does not adequately cover the definition of `:empty` - see the OP's self-answer. Using the Selectors API to test the element is pretty much *the* way to check if an element matches a, well, selector, because then you don't have to try and reimplement the selector assuming the browser already implements it correctly. The only issue is of course as stated, browser support - `matches()` did not appear in the spec until [API level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2).

Comment: Wouldn't this be subject to bad browser implementations of `:empty` or bugs in the CSS engine? But I hope you can prove me wrong, this looks more robust. I'd like something consistent.

Comment: @rvighne Yes—it assumes a proper CSS engine. It matches how the CSS would compute.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [jQuery's implementation of `:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector) matches the spec exactly, so it can be used as a reference. From the [latest version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) as of this writing:

```
"empty": function( elem ) {
    // http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo
    // :empty is only affected by element nodes and content nodes(including text(3), cdata(4)),
    //   not comment, processing instructions, or others
    // Thanks to Diego Perini for the nodeName shortcut
    //   Greater than "@" means alpha characters (specifically not starting with "#" or "?")
    for ( elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling ) {
        if ( elem.nodeName > "@" || elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 4 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: OP also defined `:empty` as **..whose data has a non-zero length**

Comment: That's not the OP's definition, that's what the spec says. It depends on how you interpret it. See my comments under their answer.

Comment: Sizzle's technique is similar but simpler: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/1.10.18/dist/sizzle.js#L1327-1338 Both seem solid.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest and easiest way to do this is :

```
    elem = document.getElemntById('id_of_the_elem');
    function isEmpty(elem){
        if(elem.innerHTML=='') console.log("empty tag");
        else console.log('Non empty tag');
    }
```

Comment: What is there's an empty element inside? It will work improperly in that case.