# Determine/Find if an HTML DIV element is empty or not used using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is another post that could have possibly answered my question.  In order to have found that post, I would have needed to search for `child nodes` or `children`.  But the problem is, that I didn't know what child nodes or HTML children were at the time.

This is NOT a jQuery question.

My question is: How is it determined whether an HTML element is empty, or not used?  For example:

```
<div id="UserRegistration"></div>
```

The above `<div>` element has no content.  As opposed to this:

```
<div id="UserRegistration">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Your New Password" required maxlength="32"/>
    <label>Verify Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="ReEnterPassword" id="reenterpassword" required maxlength="32"/><br/>  
</div>
```

I am intentionally leaving elements empty, and then injecting HTML into them later when the user clicks a menu tab.  But I do not want to inject the same HTML multiple times if the user clicks the menu item multiple times.  To avoid this, I want the code to determine whether the element has already been injected with content.  I want to use Web API interface and JavaScript.  Content is added using `.innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('UserRegistration').innerHTML=VariableWithRetreivedContent;
```

When the user clicks the `Register` menu tab, a function runs.  I've tried using this to determine if content has been added already or not, but it doesn't work:

```
function goToRegistration(ElmtToGoTo, FileToGet) {
    //Use getElementById to get info from the ElmtToGoTo DIV
    // and put info into the el variable
    var el = document.getElementById(ElmtToGoTo);
    alert(el.value);
    // If element is already filled quit
    if (el.value === undefined || el.value === "")
      {
         /To Do:  Quit Here
      };

        //To Do: Get content and put it into DIV element
      };
```

What I get is `undefined` whether the DIV has anything in it or not.  How can I test for whether the `<div>` element has already been injected with content?

Comment: I would recommend looking at this post here.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2161646/3342157

Comment: You are using the value property, which is only valid for input elments, if you want to know if certain element in particular you could check if it has childNodes by accesing to it like el.childNodes.lenght and checking is not 0, or storing the innerHTML or innerText of that element into a variable and checkig if it is an empty string, the latter (innerText) might be better suited for you if you didn't inject html on it but text.

Comment: I've used the terminology of finding CONTENT in the DIV rather than looking for nodes or children inside of the DIV element.  At the time I asked the question, I wouldn't have even thought to search for anything to do with nodes or children in a DIV element.  And it's not clear to me that just one word of text in a DIV, or maybe even an errant space would be considered a child inside the DIV or a node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elements generally don't have a `value` property, only form control elements have such a property (e.g. [`input` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties)). So, `.value` will *always* be `undefined` for div elements.

You can check how many [**child nodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) the element has. If it has none, the element is empty:

```
if (el.childNodes.length === 0)
```

---

If you only consider **Element nodes** as "content", you can use `.children` instead:

```
if (el.children.length === 0)
```

`.children` is a list of element nodes. If your element only contains text, and you don't consider that as content, `.children` would be empty.

Comment: Oh dang i was too slow, this is how you do it =)

Comment: Very nice. Alternatively, I like to do it this way: `if( element.firstChild ) { /* element is non-empty */ }` or `if( ! element.firstChild ) { /* element is empty */ }`.

Comment: What if I had this text in the DIV `<div>Placeholder</div>`  Will that text `Placeholder` be considered a child node?

Comment: @SandyGood: Yes, text nodes are children too. Even a space is a text node: `<div> </div>`. See my edit.

Comment: divelement.children.length was enough for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function goToRegistration(ElmtToGoTo, FileToGet) {
//Use getElementById to get info from the ElmtToGoTo DIV
// and put info into the el variable
 if(ElmtToGoTo){
 var el = document.getElementById(ElmtToGoTo);
}else
{
    alert("invalid element");
    return false;
}
//alert(el.innerHTML);
// If element is already filled quit
if (el.innerHTML === "") {
    el.innerHTML='<label>Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Your New Password" required maxlength="32"/> <label>Verify Password:</label><input type="password" name="ReEnterPassword" id="reenterpassword" required maxlength="32"/><br/>';
};

// To Do: Get content and put it into DIV element
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){
  goToRegistration('UserRegistration');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xZHe9/3/

Comment: Does `.innerHTML` *ever* return `undefined`?

Comment: no. sorry my mistake. i have updated the code. thanks...:)