# Is it possible to make an HTML div blurred with no elements inside?

Tags: html, containers, blur

I want to blur the background of a dive or any html containers without its inside elements.
Well I tried googling for it and found that it can be through html2canvas (creating image from beneath objects and then blur it) and also using -webkit-backdrop-filter has no effect yet.
What I want is a live blurred container similar to windows 10 menus background in the screenshot bellow.

[image: Windows 10 menu with blurry background]

Answer (score 0):

I would blur the original background using Photoshop or something, and then put it as a background image and play with the position. like this:

```
container {
 background-image: url("blurredbg.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 30px 0px;
}
```

please refer to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) for more information about background positioning.

You can, of course, control the positioning dynamically with `container.style.backgroundPosition="100% 0";` in javascript

Comment: remdevtec thank you, but here not a div or any html container is blurred nor it is a live blur. I have group of live elements that use transitions and slides like tiles (in windows 8), and the same time I have a popover menu that lies over these live elements. And here I want to blur the BG of the menu (not the live tiles image) as mentioned in above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the following stackoverflow answer to 
[check if div have elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript)
.
if elements are not present then you can use 
**document.getElementById("yourId").blur();**  to blur your div you can refer [learn more about blur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp)