# How to check is cell filled?JS

Tags: javascript

I have simple table with two cells. I change w3 school code(for drag and drop) to one image, when drag over second, take second image place and second image disappears. But problem come when there is no image in cell, then cell is gone. How to check is there image in cell?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var el = ev.target.parentNode;
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    var x = el.classList.contains('dropzone');
    if (!x) {
    ev.target.remove();
  }
}
```

```css
th, td{
  border: solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
}
table{
 width:  300px;
  }
img{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" id="a8" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/27700000/desert-windows-7-vista-and-xp-picks-27752343-500-375.jpg"></td>
    <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" id="b8" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/27700000/jellyfish-windows-7-vista-and-xp-picks-27753183-500-375.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think your `ev.target.parentNode` it's the `tr` itself - what do you try to achieve? you want to copy the image from first `td` to second `td` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop throught **td** elements and add **ondrop** event in you javascript code, *So you can know which element has fired the event*.

Then check if this element has a child inside.
If not => don't perform action *(no image elements inside)*, else => perform action  *(there is an image elements inside)*.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

var td=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i=0; i < td.length;i++){   //bind ondrop event to all td, so it will be easier to get the element which fired the event
  td[i].ondrop=function(ev){ 
     ev.preventDefault();
     if (this.hasChildNodes()) {  //check if got children nodes (if got img inside)
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var el = ev.target.parentNode;
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    var x = el.classList.contains('dropzone');
    if (!x) {
    ev.target.remove();
  }
  }
    
  
  }
}
```

```css
th, td{
  border: solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
}
table{
 width:  300px;
  }
img{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" id="a8" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/27700000/desert-windows-7-vista-and-xp-picks-27752343-500-375.jpg"></td>
    <td ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" id="b8" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/27700000/jellyfish-windows-7-vista-and-xp-picks-27753183-500-375.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For more details how to check if element has any children, check answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you this was from huge help. Especially link. thx again