# Check if html tag contains text node

Tags: javascript, html

I have a popup modal in Shopify, I'm using text node instead of innerHtml for security concerns. However, everytime I open the popup modal, the text node keeps getting appended to my h1 tag. Is there any way to check if the node already has been appended? (I don't want to use a boolean value to check if text node has been appended)

html:

```
<h1 id="ProductHeading" class="product__title product__title--template"></h1>
<h2 id="ProductHeadingModal" class="product__title product__title--template product__title--modal"></h2>
```

javascript:

```
var title = document.createTextNode(product.title);
// Product heading is an element with h1 tag
var productHeading = document.getElementById("ProductHeading"); 

if(// how to check if element has no node?) {
  productHeading.appendChild(title);
}
```

the entire javascript block:

```
window.onload = () => {
  if (window.__shgProductInits.length) {
    window.__shgProductInits.forEach((ele) => {
      let proId = document.getElementById(ele.uuid);
      proId.setAttribute('url', ele.productHandle);
      proId.style.cursor='pointer';
      proId.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let productHandle = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('url');
        fetch('/products/'+productHandle+'.js')
          .then((res) =>{return res.json()})
          .then((product) => { 
            console.log(product)
            var product = product;
            document.getElementsByClassName("product-modal")[0].style.display = "block";
            
            var title = document.createTextNode(product.title);
            var productHeading = document.getElementById("ProductHeading");
            var productHeadingModal = document.getElementById("ProductHeadingModal");
            
            if(!(productHeading.hasChildNodes())) {
                productHeading.appendChild(title);
                productHeadingModal.appendChild(title);
                
                var price = document.createTextNode("$" + parseInt(product.price).toFixed(2));
                document.getElementById("product-price").appendChild(price);
            }
            document.getElementById("product-image").src = product.images[0];
          });
      });
    });
  }
```

ProductHeading itself is not a node (I think). And checking innerHtml for length doesn't work as it is always 0

Update:

I've added the conditional check, it still returns false everytime I open the modal.

My code:
[image]

My browser console:
[image]

My website displays: 
[image]

Inspect element in browser: 
[image]

Comment: Please post an html so along with the js so could provide a working example. becouse any of the answer below should have worked for you.

Comment: I've updated with the html and javascript. I'm using script tags on a liquid platform in Shopify Shogun (liquid is a templating language like html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A couple of ways:**

```
if (element.firstChild) {
    // It has at least one
}
```

or the `hasChildNodes()` function:

```
if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
    // It has at least one
}
```

or the **length property** of childNodes:

```
if (element.childNodes.length > 0) { // Or just `if (element.childNodes.length)`
    // It has at least one
}
```

So you can just write this

```
var title = document.createTextNode(product.title);
// Product heading is an element with h1 tag
var productHeading = document.getElementById("ProductHeading"); 

if(!(productHeading.hasChildNodes())) {
  productHeading.appendChild(title);
}
```

Referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript) answer

Comment: hi Alex thanks for the prompt answer, I've updated my issue - hasChildNodes doesn't seem to work

Comment: And if you add the braces inside your condition `if(!(productHeading.hasChildNodes())` ?

Comment: yea I've updated to (!(productHeading.hasChildNodes())) still appears to keep appending

Comment: Okay I thought because in your screenshoots the braces were missing. Okay I will take a look at it

Comment: For me it works, did I miss something here? https://jsfiddle.net/2mxd4wjb/#&togetherjs=lC1IpBTMx0

I try to append it twice but it will only do it once because after the first insertion it has childnodes

Comment: hey alex thanks for your help appreciate it! apparently as alen said somehow they are not registering as nodes..I'm trying out his method now

Comment: Okay I'm curious because in my fiddle it worked

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z71qnd4b/ i print the child node length first it is 0 then it is one after appending a text node maybe there is a difference in different version

Comment: Can you maybe send me a fiddle of your code that I can reproduce your error?

Comment: hey alex! I've found the source of the problem - somehow the text nodes are not appended to productHeading but productHeadingModal instead. I've updated my method to productHeadingModal.hasChildNodes() - thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay well, NP :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (productHeading.hasChildNodes()) {

}
```