# How can i stop adding the table after the table is shown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and a HTML static table. Now, my job is to show that html table on pop-up window on clicking that button using bootstrap modal feature(imagine this case is similar to preview function where user clicks on preview button, he would see what he have given as input in the table.) I am currently working on a dummy table and I was almost done in showing the table.

But, here comes the problem.. when after clicking close button the popped up window is getting closed and If i clicked that preview button again, I am seeing two tables in the popped up window. Please find below code snippets(HTML table and JS script).

Help me out how i can avoid getting the table added again after closing the popup.

```js
function addTable() {
  var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  var oldtble = document.getElementById('table1');
  table.border = '1';
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tr.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
      td.width = '75';
      td.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  tableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-hover" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>You are mine</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="button1" onclick="addTable();">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myTableBody">
          <h5 class="lead" id="tableStruct">Make some coding to display that table</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="table_script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Result:

[image: Before clicking the button]

[image: After clicking the button]

[image: Seeing the table added after closing the popup window]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every time you click the button, it will create another new element of the table.

So, You only need to check the Modal-body table if it has already a child-element of table or if it has 2 children already.

You can select the modal-body by: `var modalbody = document.querySelector('.modal-body');`

And check the childElementCount on it:   `if (modalbody.childElementCount <= 1) { your function}`

You can also learn more about here on how to check the children on the elements: [How to check if element has any children in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript)

```js
function addTable() {
  var modalbody = document.querySelector('.modal-body');
  if (modalbody.childElementCount <= 1) {
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var oldtble = document.getElementById('table1');
    table.border = '1';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('TR');
      tr.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
      for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '75';
        td.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML));
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
    }
    tableDiv.appendChild(table);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-hover" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>You are mine</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="button1" onclick="addTable();">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myTableBody">
          <h5 class="lead" id="tableStruct">Make some coding to display that table</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="table_script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addTable() {
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var oldtble = document.getElementById('table1');
    table.border='1';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tr.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD');
            td.width= '75';
            td.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
     if(table == ""){
       $(".lead").css("display", "block");
     }
     else{
       tableDiv.innerHTML = '';
       tableDiv.appendChild(table);
     }
   
}
```

```css
/* CSS styles */
.lead{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="table1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td >Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>You are mine</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="button1" onclick="addTable();">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="myTableBody"></div>
            <h5 class="lead" id="tableStruct">Make some coding to display that table</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="table_script.js"></script>
</html>
```

:: Here I make some changes ::

1. add a CSS to `lead` class that is in the modal.
2. add a div into the modal body and shift the Id `myTableBody` into that div.
3. and add few lines at the bottom of the js function which will clear the previous table and manipulate the line "Make some coding to display that table" according to the data.