# How to check if a HTML document is empty via JavaScript without causing layout/reflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, dom

Need to check if an HTML div is empty and contains no text and no child elements as such inside it - a black page only.

e.g

```
function isPageEmpty(page) {
    const paragraphNodes = page.querySelectorAll(".paragraph");
    if ((paragraphNodes[0].children[0]).innerText !== "") {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

What would be the best way to do it, current code causing re calculation of styles?

> Accessing the innerText is causing forced re-calculation of styling.

Above code snippet is not complete as it is just to indicate what wanted to achieve.

Open for suggestion and new ideas.

Comment: First I got you want to check if the page is empty, then your function makes it limited to paragraphNodes only? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Read `textContent` [instead of `innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if element has any children in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161634/how-to-check-if-element-has-any-children-in-javascript)

Comment: You tagged it performance but then are using `querySelectorAll` but discarding all but the first element.

Comment: Actually, this code throws an error when `paragraphNodes` is empty.

Comment: Above code is not complete, but just wanted to provide insight of what wanted to achieve - main goal is that re-calculation of style should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check if an element is empty (no text or child elements without text) is to use `!element.textContent.trim().length`.
The `trim()` function will also ensure that spaces are not considered as content either.

```js
const ELEMENTS = document.querySelectorAll('p');

ELEMENTS.forEach(element => {
  element.classList.toggle('border-red', !element.textContent.trim().length);
});
```

```css
.border-red {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Element with content</h2>
<p>Content</p>

<h2>Element with content inside child element</h2>
<p><span>Content</span></p>

<h2>Empty element</h2>
<p></p>

<h2>Elements with only empty child elements</h2>
<p><span></span></p>
```